# It is possible to check the extension of a file stored on assets folder?

Tags: android, assets, fileinputstream, android-file, android-assets

I have the name of a file `img2455`, but i dont have the extension. It is possible to check the extension of that file?

It can be stored on assets folder as `.jpg`, `.png` or `.bmp`, but i dont know, i must check it. ¿How can i do it?

Now i am accessing the file with a content provider forzing the extension as `.jpg`, and it works when it is jpg, but it fails when the file haves bmp or png extension. This is my code:

`theUri = Uri.parse("content://"+getPackageName()+"/"+file.getName()+".jpg");`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the file's path or name in a String. Check if it `endsWith()` ".jpg" or ".png" or ".bmp" and then take appropriate action.

```
String filePath = "/assets/someFile.jpg";

if (filePath.endsWith(".jpg"))
  Log.d("JPG", "Got a JPG");
else if(filePath.endsWith(".png"))
  Log.d("PNG", "Got a PNG");
else if(filePath.endsWith(".bmp"))
  Log.d("BMP", "Got a BMP");
else Log.d("?", "Got some BS");
```

Comment: i dont have the filepath, i dont have the extension, i just have someFile, not someFile.jpg

Comment: I see that you are doing `file.getName()` above. Use this value. It will have the extension, which you can use, as the above snippet describes.